# Problems with ATOI in x86 NASM Linux assembly

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I don't understand how to convert a string to an integer.

This is for homework, **but** I do not want answers to the problem -- (AKA Correct code). I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain just what it is that i'm doing wrong! :(

Thanks in advance!!!

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a virtual machine, 32 bit.

I compile with:

```
nasm -f elf proj2.asm
```

I link with:

```
gcc -o proj2 proj2.o
```

and then run it:

```
./proj2
```

It displays the first number, but then gives me a segmentation fault when I try to use `atoi`.

I have a teacher who wants us to:

1. read in numbers from a text file arranged as so:

   ```
   4
   5
   4
   2
   9
   ```

(there is whitespace before each integer)

As per his instructions: "Be sure to read seven (7) characters into the buffer to get the entire line. These are the five characters representing the number together with characters CR and LF.  CR is the Carriage Return character with hex code `0x0D` and LF is the Line Feed character with hex code `0x0A`.")

I've erased the spaces from the file, and tried to read it that way, but it didn't help.

The ints are to be read, into an array on the stack, with a maximum number of ints of 250. That's not the problem though :/

Below is my code so far.

```
    BUFFERSIZE equ 10

section .data
    file_name: db "/home/r/Documents/CS/project2/source/indata.txt", 0x00
    file_mode: db "r", 0x00
    output: db "%i",0xa
    test: db "hello world",10
    format: db "%u"
    numToRead: db 1
    temp: db "hi"
    num:db "1",0,0
section .bss
    fd:    resd 4
    length:    resd 4
    buffer resb BUFFERSIZE
                            ;i was trying to use buffers and just
                            ;read through each character in the string, 
                            ;but i couldn't get it to work
section .text 
 extern fopen
 extern  atoi
 extern printf
 extern fscanf

 extern fgets
 extern getc
 extern fclose
 global main

main: 
                    ;setting up stack frame
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp 

                    ;opens file, store FD to eax
    push    file_mode
    push    file_name
    call    fopen

                    ;save FD from eax into fd    
    push    eax
    mov     ebx,eax
    mov     [fd],ebx

                    ;ebx holds the file descriptor
                    ;push in reverse order
    push    ebx
    push    numToRead
    push    temp
    call    fgets    

    push  eax
    call printf     ;prints length (this works, i get a 4. 
                    ;Changing the number in the file changes the number displayed. 
                    ;I can also read in several lines, just can't get any ints! 
                    ;(So i can't do any comparisons or loops :/ )


                    ;i shouldn't need to push eax here, right? 
                    ;It's already at the top of the stack from the printf
    ;pop  eax
    ;push eax
    call atoi
                        ;calling atoi gives me a segmentation fault error
    push eax
    call printf

    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp 
    ret
```

edit:
Interestingly, I can call atoi just fine. It's when i then try to

```
push eax
call atoi 
push eax
call printf
```

that i get segmentation faults.

Comment: Your input file uses Windows-style CR-LF line endings rather than Unix/Linux-style LF line endings?

Comment: I believe so, i guess i'm not sure what the difference is--aren't they the same?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but when i DO get output (so if i call printf before calling atoi), it's of the form:

(spaces=_-_-_)
-_-_-_4

So, i'm getting the line just fine. It's the converting to integer that's not working :/

Comment: No, they're not the same. Windows-style text files terminate each line with a 2-character sequence CR and LF (`'\r'`, `'\n'` in C syntax). Unix-style text files use just a single LF character. In C, text-mode I/O automatically translates line endings to `'\n'` as needed, so if you're using `getc` and `fscanf` for input. But if you're dealing with a file in a non-native format, it's more complicated.

Comment: `push numToRead` pushes the address of your variable (way too many bytes to read!). You want to push [contents] - you'll have to say "dword"... and it will have to BE a dword. If your instructor says read 7 bytes, that's probably what you should do - and make sure your buffer has room for 7 bytes! (make it 8 bytes - room for the terminating zero) I'm not sure if that'll solve your problem with `atoi`, but it's the first problem I see. `push BUFFERSIZE` would be correct - it's a constant, not a variable.

Comment: Keith: It's using the ascii CR/LF as per: http://www.asciitable.com/
I suppose i'm a little confused as to what you mean by using Windows-Style: Isn't using 0xa and 0xd  *Nix format? 

Frank: As per the fgets page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

It says to use num as 
    Maximum number of characters to be copied into str (including the terminating null-character). I want to read in all 8?

Thanks both! :)

Comment: No, if the number given to fgets includes the terminating zero, 7 should be okay...

Comment: thanks frank! I'm currently trying a complete rewrite incorporating all aspects of the comments/answers. I'll let you know how it goes in about 20 mins!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless I cannot see it on my cellphone, but your not balancing the stack after your calls.  those c functions are not stdcall so you have to adjust the stack after each call.  I do:

`add   esp, 4 * numofpushes`  that might be the source of your seg faults.

Comment: Hi Gunmer,

You are correct that i'm not balancing the stack after my calls. Does it matter though? At the top I preserve my stack pointer and at the bottom return it--is that not Standard operating procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: (I just tried adding the add esp 4*numofpushes, no dice :/ ) thanks though!

Comment: Does it matter?  YES IT MATTERS!!!!  Your learning Assembly?  Learn to do it the correct way in the beginning and you will have less problems later on.  Most C functions DO NOT clean up the stack, YOU have to do it!!!  And you did change numofpushes to an actuall number right?

Comment: I did indeed. I'm just trying to rewrite the whole thing with correct pushes right now. 

As far as pushes go, as long as i dont change the specification (a32/a16) push will always put 4 bytes on top of the stack; right?

Comment: OOOOOHKAY

you were right. 

Thank you very much for calling that to my attention--i will be fastidious in my add esp,4's from now on.

Comment: It it NOT just `add esp, 4`.  For your fopen, you are pushing 2 parameters, so you need to do `add esp, 4 * 2` after the call.  For fgets, you are pushing 3 parameters, so you need `add esp, 4 * 3`.  Understand??

Comment: yes'sir!

so if, for example i push eax, push ebx, push ecx, push DWORD[foo], push esp, i'd add esp,20!

:D

Answer (score 0):

> edit: Interestingly, I can call atoi just fine. It's when i then try to

```
  push eax
  call atoi 
  push eax
  call printf
```

> that i get segmentation faults.

From the [atoi reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/): *"On success, the function returns the converted integral number as an int value."*.
Passing any random integer (like `4`) as the first argument of the following `printf` (i.e. the `format` string pointer) is not likely to end well.

Comment: (Currently running through my code again to make sure that this is not in fact the problem. I truly hope it is though!)